# 4G wireless router -> LAN cables

Tags: networking

What I have:

- 4G wireless router that gives a wireless network. Working fine, can connect to it and use internet from that.
- 2 cameras that only have ethernet ports, not possible to connect via wireless network.

The cameras needs internet. Is there any router that provides two (or more) lan connections, and can utilize the internet connection from the wireless network that the 4G router creates?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most wireless routers come with 4-5 Ethernet ports. If yours does not look into Wireless Access Points. Most of these (like DLink or Linksys) for example, have a client mode that will translate the incoming Ethernet signal to wireless and connect to a router.

Comment: Most chances those routers wouldn't be using 4G/LTE but regular PPPoE/PPPoA(DSL), wouldn't they ?

Comment: You most likely have a router with a built in Access Point for 4G. The router part if handling the actually 802.11 wireless signal that your computer are using to connect. The Access point would connect to the 802.11 wireless signal, and the router would handle the 4G internet signal.

Comment: @Kwaio It won't matter, since that router won't be connected to the Internet but to the wireless LAN created by the 4G router.

Answer (score 0):

What I personally would do would be to either purchase a wireless bridge (recieves a wireless signal and then you can use an ethernet cable from one of the ports) or you can flash an old router with something like DD-WRT and build the bridge yourself.  I used an old Linksys router, put DD-WRT on it, and used it to bridge a Verizon Mi-Fi spot to a desktop so I didn't have to buy a wireless adapter, and I also then had 4 other ports on the back if needed.

If you do choose to go this route, then here is the [DD-WRT literature](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Bridge)
on a wireless bridge and [more literature](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installation) on installing and hardware compatibility.  It's a cool and easy project in my opinion.